# Retrieve image from database and display in a table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image

I need to do something like this.

> [image]

These are the payments types accepted by a store. How can I display the corresponding image of each payment types. Images are from the database and the payment types to be displayed are based on what payment types are available in a store. I tried using switch case, and here's the result

> [image]

Here's my code:

_DeliveryDetailsPartial

```
<table class="table table-noborder col-md-3" style="margin-top: 10px;">
    <tr>
        <th style="text-transform:uppercase; padding:5px; font-weight:bold" colspan=" 4">Payments Accepted</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (ReferenceAcceptedPayment payment in Model.Item4)
    {
        <tr style="text-align: center">
            switch (payment.PaymentID)
            {
            case 1:
                <td colspan="1"><img src="~/Content/Images/amex.png"></td>
                break;

            case 2:
                <td colspan="1"><img src="~/Content/Images/discover.png"></td>
                break;

            case 3:
                <td colspan="1"><img src="~/Content/Images/mastercard.png"></td>
                break;

            case 4:
                <td colspan="1"><img src="~/Content/Images/visa.png"></td>
                break;

            case 5:
                <td colspan="1"><img src="~/Content/Images/giftcard.png"></td>
                break;

            case 6:
                <td colspan="1"><img src="~/Content/Images/cash.png"></td>
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

DeliveryDetailController

```
    public ActionResult NewAddress(string id)
    {
        GetStoreDetails();
        return View();
    }
```

GetStoreDetails

```
    public ActionResult GetStoreDetails(string id)
    {
        var store = new Tuple<List<Store>, List<StoreHour>, List<StoreHour>, List<ReferenceAcceptedPayment>>
        (_repo.GetStore(id), _repo.GetStoreHourByDay(dayOftheWeek), _repo.GetStoreHourByID(int.Parse(id)), _repo.GetStoreAcceptedPayment(int.Parse(id)));

        return View(store);
    }
```

Comment: I don't know mvc, but seems that the browser see the line "switch (payment.PaymentID)" as html, you can try to add a @ brfore this line

Comment: you should add @ before @switch (payment.PaymentID) also if I were you I will not use this switch statement as with every new payment method you will have to change your code, You can rename your images to be similar to your id something like payment.image.id.png such as payment.image.1.png and so on.

Comment: hi @bdn02 :do you have any idea on how i can limit the number of payment types per row to 4? If payment types retrieved is more than 4, let say 5, the 5th image should be on the next line. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Action method that returns image  call your Controller's Action(DislpayImage()) from the View like this:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("DislpayImage", "Controller",new { id=Model.Id })" alt="myimage" />
```

Just pass the id of the image you want to display to Controller action

```
public class ImageController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult DislpayImage( int id )
    {
        var imageData = ...get bytes from database...

        return File( imageData, "image/jpg" );
    }
}
```

Now pass the id of image which you want to display in your view, like this:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("DislpayImage", "Controller", new { id="2" })" alt="myimage" />
```

Now you will get the image with id as 2.